# Google map api v3 markers exclude a city or certain bound

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I am using google maps api v3. I have a database of markers with lat and long address that I display on a map and that works fine.

The map is displaying markers for entire state and now I want to know how can exclude markers in a certain city? Say I am displaying a map of Indiana and want to exclude Indianapolis.

I have a rough idea where I can select the points and some how check if they are between a certain range but could someone elaborate on this with a more specific example or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is something called [Reverse Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding), which will give you result of street name, city name and country name, given longitude latitude example.

I will do these steps :

1. Iterate all the marker and "reverse geocoding" the marker lat-long.
2. Check city result of the "reverse geocoding".
3. If the City is not inside your accepted cities, remove the marker.